# Color a specific word in every line of text in a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, highlight

I want to color every same word inside a RichTextBox. I can do it for one line but not on multiple lines.
E.g., Welcome "user" .....

I want the word `user` to be an exact color in every line it's found.
Here's with what i came up so far:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "Welcome "
RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength, 0)
RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = My.Settings.color
RichTextBox1.AppendText(My.Settings.username)
RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black
RichTextBox1.AppendText(" ........." + vbCrLf)
```

It's on `form.Load`; I tried to use the `richtextbox.TextChange` event, but it just colors the last `user` word and the others are remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple Class that enables multiple Selections and Highlights of text for RichTextBox and TextBox controls.
You can use multiple instances of this Class for different controls.

You can add the Words to Select/HighLight to a List and specify which color to use for selecting and/or highlighting the text.

```
Dim listOfWords As WordList = New WordList(RichTextBox1)

listOfWords.AddRange({"Word1", "Word2"})
listOfWords.SelectionColor = Color.LightBlue
listOfWords.HighLightColor = Color.Yellow
```

These are the visual results of the Class actions:

[image: RichTextBox Text Select and HighLight]

In the example, the List of words is filled using:

```
Dim patterns As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split()
listOfWords.AddRange(patterns)
```

In the visual example, the Class is configured this way:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim patterns As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split()

    Dim listOfWords As WordList = New WordList(RichTextBox1)
    listOfWords.AddRange(patterns)
    listOfWords.SelectionColor = Color.LightBlue
    listOfWords.HighLightColor = Color.Yellow

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        listOfWords.WordsSelect()
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        listOfWords.WordsHighLight()
    Else
        listOfWords.DeselectAll()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the Class used to generate the Selections and HighLights:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class WordList
    Private TextRendererFlags As TextFormatFlags =
        TextFormatFlags.Top Or TextFormatFlags.Left Or TextFormatFlags.NoPadding Or
        TextFormatFlags.WordBreak Or TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl

    Private textControl As RichTextBox = Nothing
    Private wordsList As List(Of Word)

    Public Sub New(rtb As RichTextBox)
        textControl = rtb
        wordsList = New List(Of Word)
        ProtectSelection = False
    End Sub

    Public Property ProtectSelection As Boolean
    Public Property HighLightColor As Color
    Public Property SelectionColor As Color

    Public Sub Add(word As String)
        wordsList.Add(New Word() With {.Word = word, .Indexes = GetWordIndexes(word)})
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddRange(words As String())
        For Each WordItem As String In words
            wordsList.Add(New Word() With {.Word = WordItem, .Indexes = GetWordIndexes(WordItem)})
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Function GetWordIndexes(word As String) As List(Of Integer)
        Return Regex.Matches(textControl.Text, word).
                     OfType(Of Match)().
                     Select(Function(chr) chr.Index).ToList()
    End Function

    Public Sub DeselectAll()
        If textControl IsNot Nothing Then
            textControl.SelectAll()
            textControl.SelectionBackColor = textControl.BackColor
            textControl.Update()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub WordsHighLight()
        If wordsList.Count > 0 Then
            For Each WordItem As Word In wordsList
                For Each Position As Integer In WordItem.Indexes
                    Dim p As Point = textControl.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Position)
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(textControl.CreateGraphics(), WordItem.Word,
                                          textControl.Font, p, textControl.ForeColor,
                                          HighLightColor, TextRendererFlags)
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub WordsSelect()
        DeselectAll()
        If wordsList.Count > 0 Then
            For Each WordItem As Word In wordsList
                For Each Position As Integer In WordItem.Indexes
                    textControl.Select(Position, WordItem.Word.Length)
                    textControl.SelectionColor = textControl.ForeColor
                    textControl.SelectionBackColor = SelectionColor
                    textControl.SelectionProtected = ProtectSelection
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Friend Class Word
        Property Word As String
        Property Indexes As List(Of Integer)
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

With a module,you can do it this way :

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Utility

<Extension()>
Sub HighlightText(ByVal myRtb As RichTextBox, ByVal word As String, ByVal color As Color)
    If word = String.Empty Then Return
    Dim index As Integer, s_start As Integer = myRtb.SelectionStart, startIndex As Integer = 0
    While(__InlineAssignHelper(index, myRtb.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex))) <> -1
        myRtb.[Select](index, word.Length)
        myRtb.SelectionColor = color
        startIndex = index + word.Length
    End While

    myRtb.SelectionStart = s_start
    myRtb.SelectionLength = 0
    myRtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black
End Sub

<Obsolete("Please refactor code that uses this function, it is a simple work-around to simulate inline assignment in VB!")>
Private Shared Function __InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function
End Module
```

Or , you can also go with this one as it will allow you to highlight multiple words at the same time :

```
 Private Sub HighlightWords(ByVal words() As String)
     Private Sub HighlightWords(ByVal words() As String)
    For Each word As String In words
        Dim startIndex As Integer = 0

        While (startIndex < rtb1.TextLength)
            Dim wordStartIndex As Integer = rtb1.Find(word, startIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
            If (wordStartIndex <> -1) Then
                rtb1.SelectionStart = wordStartIndex
                rtb1.SelectionLength = word.Length
                rtb1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            Else
                Exit While
            End If

            startIndex += wordStartIndex + word.Length
        End While

    Next
End Sub
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851908/highlight-all-searched-word-in-richtextbox) Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried tweaking both of the codes to match my project but neither of those actually helped .

Comment: what do u mean ? It should work ..can u show the code u tried ?

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
Public Sub HighlightText(ByVal txt As String, ByVal obj As RichTextBox)

    obj.SelectionStart = 0
    obj.SelectAll()
    obj.SelectionBackColor = Color.White


    Dim len = txt.Length
    Dim pos = obj.Find(txt, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
    While (pos >= 0)
        obj.Select(pos, len)
        obj.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
        If pos + len >= obj.Text.Length Then
            Exit While
        End If
        pos = obj.Find(txt, pos + len, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub HighlightText(ByVal txt As String, ByVal obj As RichTextBox)

    obj.SelectionStart = 0
    obj.SelectAll()
    obj.SelectionBackColor = Color.White


    Dim len = txt.Length
    Dim pos = obj.Find(txt, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
    While (pos >= 0)
        obj.Select(pos, len)
        obj.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
        If pos + len >= obj.Text.Length Then
            Exit While
        End If
        pos = obj.Find(txt, pos + len, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
    End While
End Sub
```